# Berlekamp algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to understand Berlekamp's algorithm on very simple examples.

For example, we know that $X+1$ and $X^2+X+1$ are irreducible on $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, so $$P(X)=(X+1)(X^2+X+1)=X^3+1$$ is not. But my "computation" of the Berlekamp algorithm says $P$ is irreducible.

Let note $\alpha : Q(X)\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]\to Q(X)^2\in \mathbb{F}_2[X]$, we have

$$ \begin{array}{l}
\alpha(1)\equiv 1~\mathrm{mod}[P] \\
\alpha(X)\equiv X^2~\mathrm{mod}[P]\\
\alpha(X^2)\equiv -X~\mathrm{mod}[P]
\end{array}$$

So the matrix of $\alpha$ in the basis $(1,X,X^2)$ is

$$ M = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\quad \quad \mathrm{and}\quad \quad M-I_3 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{array}\right)$$

So we have $\dim \ker (M-I_3)=1$, which means that $P$ is the product of $1$ irreductible polynom, hence $P$ is irreducible.

> Obviously $P$ is not irreducible, but I can't find where my mistake is.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $M-I_3$ has rank 1 (remember, $1=-1$), so kernel has dimension 2.

Comment: oh... I see thank you @GerryMyerson (I think that is a Turkey drawback)